# .html vs .php | Difference, when I write php in both extension types

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I know that we can write PHP in .html format if we edit the .htaccess file.

```
ddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

What is the difference between editing .htaccess and write PHP codes in .html file and writing PHP codes in .php file?

Comment: No difference. Search engines and browsers are caring about content-type and content received by given URL. The only difference is when you are mixing a lot of static `.html` pages with a few scripts - it is not wise to send unnecessary information to the php interpreter.

Comment: Agreed. You're putting unnecessary load on your server if you don't have PHP in every file named `.html`. Have you considered url-rewriting? You will achieve the same client-end result, but all your PHP should be ending in `.php`. Back to your question, there's no difference with respect to your clients.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference. PHP written in .html works exactly like PHP written in .php files. However, you cannot write HTML in .php files.